# I've never had a need to use the ($nn,x) addressing mode. What's an example of something it's useful for?

Tags: 6502

I've used `($nn),y` plenty of times, it's pretty much the 6502's bread-and-butter method of iterating through arrays. But I've *never* found a use for `($nn,x)`. The only time I've ever thought about using it is when `x = 0`. It seems like any problem that can be solved with `STA ($nn,x)` can just as easily be done with hardcoded pointers like in this example with writing to the Konami VRC6 sound hardware:

```
LDX #2
loop:
LDA (musicptr),y
STA $9000,x  ;pulse 1 channel regs
STA $A000,x  ;pulse 2 channel regs
STA $B000,x  ;sawtooth channel regs
DEX
BNE loop
```

Versus:

```
LDA #$00
STA $10
STA $12
STA $14
LDA #$90
STA $11
LDA #$A0
STA $13
LDA #$B0
STA $15

LDX #$00
loop:
LDA (musicptr),y
STA ($10,x)  ;first pass: STA $9000. second pass: STA $A000. third pass: STA $B000
INX
INX
CPX #6
BNE loop
```

I know that not every tool *needs* to be used, but I just can't think of a purpose for this addressing mode at all.

Comment: You're looking for an answer more complicated than: when you have a table of pointers to things?

Comment: @Tommy Actually, now that I think about it, I don't see that to be all that useful, as there's no ```($nn,x),y```, so at most you'd be able to extract 1 byte, in which case you could have just cut out the middleman and made a table of bytes that was indexed using ```($nn),y```.

Comment: by that logic there has never been a need for a table of pointers anywhere in computer science. You could always just rearrange linearly.

Comment: @puppydrum64: Some interpreters used indexed indirect for a register array in zero page, such as Steve Wozniak's [Sweet 16](http://www.6502.org/source/interpreters/sweet16.htm). See also this question and its answers over on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22436/71).

Answer (score 0):

Checking out some well-known source code of the era, from a system where the 6502 was used to build an actual OS with hardware abstraction, the BBC MOS uses `($nn,x)` in only two instances:

- [OSWORD 5](https://github.com/raybellis/mos120/blob/2e2ff80708e79553643e4b77c947b0652117731b/input/E5B3#L573) and [6](https://github.com/raybellis/mos120/blob/2e2ff80708e79553643e4b77c947b0652117731b/input/E5B3#L591), which read and write bytes to IO addresses; and
- [to write teletext characters to the screen](https://github.com/raybellis/mos120/blob/2e2ff80708e79553643e4b77c947b0652117731b/input/CDED#L317).

So:

1. this probably confirms that the addressing mode isn't especially useful — just three usages in 16kb of code, with two of those just being the read/write versions of the same operation; and
2. it demonstrates the main use case: reading or writing to somewhere via a table of pointers.

Despite your assertion as a comment above:

- IO space cannot just be made into a table of bytes indexed by `($nn),y` because it has fixed locations; and
- video memory cannot just be made into a table of bytes indexed by `($nn),y` because it has fixed locations.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no indirect mode without indexing in the original 6502, one use is to set `x` to 0 to emulate such a mode.

```
ldx #0
lda ($zp,x)
```

Yes you can do it with the `y` register and `lda ($zp),y`, but maybe `y` has got a value in it that you want to keep.

Other than that, I've got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The ($nn),Y form is used so often because it is has lots of *general purpose* uses. That is, typically when you have a pointer to something, it's more than to a single byte, so Y represents an index to a field in your multi-byte record.

The ($nn,X) form is used far less often, because it basically has a *single* purpose. But it is *very useful* for that single purpose. Essentially, it is used when you have a collection of I/O stream buffers of some kind, and you need to maintain an array of pointers to the current position in each buffer. You can store this array of pointers in the zero-page, which provides for easy access to your streams using the ($nn,X) addressing mode.

Let's say you have three input buffers, and you have pointers to the current read position in each buffer stored at `$00/$01`,`$02/$03`, and `$04/$05`, and the buffers are numbered 0, 1, and 2, respectively. Here's a sample function for reading the next byte from an input stream of your choice. Assume the desired stream number is provided in the Y register.

```
RDBUF: TYA
       ASL A
       TAX           ; calculate an index to the desired buffer pointer
       LDA ($00,X)   ; read the current byte from the buffer
       INC $00,X
       BNE DONE
       INC $01,X     ; advance the buffer pointer to the next byte
DONE:  RTS
```

The RPG classic *Ultima IV: Quest of the Avatar* uses this addressing mode on the Commodore 64 for streaming the 3 SID voices when playing music. It maintains an array of pointers in the zero-page to music sequencing streams for each of the 3 SID voices.

The CBM DOS ROM in the Commodore 64's 1541 disk drive also uses this addressing mode to manage I/O pointers for its file data buffers.

Doubtless there are many other similar uses out there.